# Text overlay over gallery

Tags: css, wordpress, fancybox

I'm trying to get a text overlay over a gallery I have on my site (I'm using Wordpress). So far I have been able to get the text overlay to appear, just not on top of the image.

Here is [the link](http://tinyurl.com/p6z3tyx) to my site. I have followed [this guide](http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/).

HTML -

```
<div class="image">
[gallery link="file" columns="4" ids="174,175,176,173"]
<h2><span>+</span></h2>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.image { 
position: relative; 
width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 { 
position: absolute; 
top: 200px; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
}

h2 span { 
color: #000; 
font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
letter-spacing: -1px;  
background:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
background:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
padding: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: That's some odd HTML. What this `[gallery link="file" columns="4" ids="174,175,176,173"]` ? Also, I can't see a gallery at all at that link.

Comment: @Paulie_D, Wordpress shortcode

Comment: As I said, no gallery is appearing. So that's the first problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D, click the img

Comment: So is the '+' supposed to be over the front page image or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Yeah, the '+' is meant to be over the image

Comment: The '+' looks like its where it's supposed to be but I cannot figure ouu the rest of the structure & positioning. My guess is that it's something in the JS.

Comment: The '+' is meant to be over the image to indicate that it's a gallery

Comment: I know where it is 'supposed' to be but it actually is positioned where you told it to be At least as far as I can tell). You seem to have stack of hidden images which then pop up in the fancybox modal. My guess is that there is something affecting the **overall** positioning of all those images that's throwing the calculations off. And that is likely to be in the JS.

Comment: Are you using a custom theme that has any WordPress shortcode overrides/filters? Are you able to use a different theme to make sure it works on another theme?

Comment: @Aibrean, I tried it on another page of the site and it worked. It's just this particular page i'm struggling with